# Each image request in the network of Flutter devtools generates a ws request

Tags: flutter, devtools, flutter-devtools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n6SI.png)

Please help，I have encountered a problem。
Each image request in the network of Flutter devtools generates a ws request

I really can't find the problem

Comment: What's your question?  Those are upgrades from http proto to ws proto.  That happens when you are connecting to ws: URIs.

Comment: The problem is that image requests will generate ws. Thank you
Randal Schwartz

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.